# CGFloat error on Physics Body in Xcode 6 beta 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

Just updated to Xcode 6 beta 7 and fixed almost all of the many errors that popped up. The one that is now driving me nuts is in this code:

```
if state != .FSGameStateEnded {
        self.moveBackground()

        if bird.physicsBody?.velocity.dy > 280 {
            bird.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(bird.physicsBody?.velocity.dx, 280)
        }

        bird.zRotation = Float.clamp(-1, max: 0.0, value: bird.physicsBody?.velocity.dy * (bird.physicsBody?.velocity.dy < 0 ? 0.003 : 0.001))
```

after .dx and .dy (in all the places they're mentioned) it keeps telling me it's unwrapped and suggests adding ? or !, but when I put either of those it suggests deleting it, which just keeps going back and forth and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I fixed it by adding an ! instead of ?, so now it looks like this:

```
if bird.physicsBody?.velocity.dy > 280 {
            bird.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(bird.physicsBody!.velocity.dx, 280)
        }

        bird.zRotation = Float.clamp(-1, max: 0.0, value: bird.physicsBody!.velocity.dy * (bird.physicsBody?.velocity.dy < 0 ? 0.003 : 0.001))
```

I hope this helps anyone who is banging their head against the wall like I was!